# How to get distinct list in GSP in Frails framework

Tags: java, grails, groovy

So I am using this in my view page

```
<g:each var="c" in="${Event.list() }">
    <li class="controller">
        ${c.event_name}
    </li>
</g:each>
```

but I need a list of distinct events

Any suggestions?

Also I need to display this distinct list in the first view page,
I have not written any controller yet, is there any other way ,like passing list from `bootstrap.groovy` to this view page ???

Comment: Use a controller to calculate/collate what data you wish to display (that's the essence of the grails framework). You only require the event name, use a createCriteria to get distinct values, sort, limit number of entries, etc in here.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`.unique()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28%29) to get the distinct items from a Collection.

```
${Event.list().unique()}
```

Ideally you should pass this info from the controller via the model, as the GSP should not really be dealing with domain classes like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a criteria query, normally used for more complex queries, which has a listDistinct method:

```
Event.createCriteria().listDistinct()
```

You can not pass anything from Bootstrap.groovy, that's only to perform setup/shutdown tasks which are global for the app, like registering dynamic methods, setting up default information, etc.

Comment: getting NPE , may be iam doing something wrong , i'll check it out myself , mean while ,in the first view , if we have to show the list of domain , is there any other way to pass a list in to this default view page

Comment: You should limit views (gsps) to displaying information, and use controllers to fetch and prepare that information, as stated by shuttsy. You can modify URLMappings and set "/" to a controller instead of the default index.gsp.